# How to use only overlay between tikz picture and equation

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

I have a working example here. I want to display tikzpicture and equation one at a time. I don't know how to use only overlay here.

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, shadows, arrows}

\tikzset{
  basic/.style  = {draw, text width=2cm, drop shadow, font=\sffamily, rectangle},
  root/.style   = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center,
                   fill=green!30},
  level 2/.style = {basic, rounded corners=6pt, thin,align=center, fill=green!60,
                   text width=8em},
  level 3/.style = {basic, thin, align=left, fill=pink!60, text width=6.5em}
}

\mode<presentation>

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      level 1/.style={sibling distance=40mm},
      edge from parent/.style={->,draw},
      >=latex]

    % root of the the initial tree, level 1
    \node[root](start) {Mass Balance};
    \draw[->,very thick](0,0) (1.2,0)--(1.9,0);
    \draw[->,very thick](-1.8,0)--(-1.1,0);
    \draw[->,very thick](0,0.6)--(0,1.4);
    \draw[->,very thick](0,-1.4)--(0,-0.6);
    \node[right of =start,xshift=2.5cm](spatialpos){$q_c(t,x+\Delta x,\tau)$};
    \node[left of =start,xshift=-1.7cm](spatialneg){$q_c(t,x,\tau)$};
    \node[above of =start,yshift=0.8cm](agepos){$c(t,x,\tau+\Delta \tau)$};
    \node[below of =start,yshift=-0.8cm](ageneg){$c(t,x,\tau)$};
    \draw[->,very thick](-4,-3)--(-4,0);
    \draw[->,very thick](-4,-3)--(-0.5,-3);
    \node[below of = ageneg,yshift=0.2cm](spatial){Spatial dim};
    \node[left of = spatialneg,yshift=0.4cm](age){Age dim.};
    \end{tikzpicture}


        \begin{align*}
         \rho \Delta x \Delta y \Delta z \Delta \tau \partial_t c_i(t,x,\tau) \\
        &= \rho \Delta x \Delta y \Delta z \Delta \tau (p_i-d_i)  \\
        &- \rho \Delta y, \Delta z \Delta \tau [q_{i,x}(t,x+\Delta x/2, y, z, \tau)\\
        &\qquad - q_{i,x}(t,x - \Delta x/2, y, z, \tau)]\\
        &- \rho \Delta x, \Delta z \Delta  \tau [q_{i,y}(t,x,y+\Delta y/2, y, z, \tau)\\
        &\qquad - q_{i,y}(t,x,y - \Delta y/2, z, z, \tau)]\\
        &- \rho \Delta x \Delta y \Delta \tau[q_{i,z}(t,x,y,z+\Delta z/2, \tau) \\
        &\qquad - q_{i,z}(t,x,y,z-\Delta z/2, \tau)]\\
            &- \rho \Delta x \Delta y \Delta \tau[q_{i,z}(t,x,y,z+\Delta z/2, \tau) \\
        &\qquad - q_{i,z}(t,x,y,z-\Delta z/2, \tau)] \\
        \end{align*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for `\only` is

```
\only<overlay specification>{text}
```

or

```
\only{text}<overlay specification>
```

and you can use virtually anything (in particular, a `tikzpicture` or a displayed equation) in the place os `text`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, shadows, arrows}

\tikzset{
  basic/.style  = {draw, text width=2cm, drop shadow, font=\sffamily, rectangle},
  root/.style   = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center,
                   fill=green!30},
  level 2/.style = {basic, rounded corners=6pt, thin,align=center, fill=green!60,
                   text width=8em},
  level 3/.style = {basic, thin, align=left, fill=pink!60, text width=6.5em}
}

\mode<presentation>

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    \only<1>{\begin{tikzpicture}
      level 1/.style={sibling distance=40mm},
      edge from parent/.style={->,draw},
      >=latex]

    % root of the the initial tree, level 1
    \node[root](start) {Mass Balance};
    \draw[->,very thick](0,0) (1.2,0)--(1.9,0);
    \draw[->,very thick](-1.8,0)--(-1.1,0);
    \draw[->,very thick](0,0.6)--(0,1.4);
    \draw[->,very thick](0,-1.4)--(0,-0.6);
    \node[right of =start,xshift=2.5cm](spatialpos){$q_c(t,x+\Delta x,\tau)$};
    \node[left of =start,xshift=-1.7cm](spatialneg){$q_c(t,x,\tau)$};
    \node[above of =start,yshift=0.8cm](agepos){$c(t,x,\tau+\Delta \tau)$};
    \node[below of =start,yshift=-0.8cm](ageneg){$c(t,x,\tau)$};
    \draw[->,very thick](-4,-3)--(-4,0);
    \draw[->,very thick](-4,-3)--(-0.5,-3);
    \node[below of = ageneg,yshift=0.2cm](spatial){Spatial dim};
    \node[left of = spatialneg,yshift=0.4cm](age){Age dim.};
    \end{tikzpicture}}


        \only<2>{\begin{align*}
         \rho \Delta x \Delta y \Delta z \Delta \tau \partial_t c_i(t,x,\tau) \\
        &= \rho \Delta x \Delta y \Delta z \Delta \tau (p_i-d_i)  \\
        &- \rho \Delta y, \Delta z \Delta \tau [q_{i,x}(t,x+\Delta x/2, y, z, \tau)\\
        &\qquad - q_{i,x}(t,x - \Delta x/2, y, z, \tau)]\\
        &- \rho \Delta x, \Delta z \Delta  \tau [q_{i,y}(t,x,y+\Delta y/2, y, z, \tau)\\
        &\qquad - q_{i,y}(t,x,y - \Delta y/2, z, z, \tau)]\\
        &- \rho \Delta x \Delta y \Delta \tau[q_{i,z}(t,x,y,z+\Delta z/2, \tau) \\
        &\qquad - q_{i,z}(t,x,y,z-\Delta z/2, \tau)]\\
            &- \rho \Delta x \Delta y \Delta \tau[q_{i,z}(t,x,y,z+\Delta z/2, \tau) \\
        &\qquad - q_{i,z}(t,x,y,z-\Delta z/2, \tau)] \\
        \end{align*}}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response. I didn't know we could put the whole section into curly braces where we want to apply the `\only` overlay.

Comment: @Jdbaba yes, the syntax for `\only` is `\only<overlay specification>{text}` or also `\only{text}<overlay specification>`.

Comment: @Jdbaba I've added this remark to my answer.

Comment: Can I ask you how did you create the animated (gif) image ? Thats very helpful to show how the code works.

Comment: @Jdbaba I first produce the PDF and then I use something like this `convert -verbose -delay 120 -loop 0 -density 300 <file>.pdf <file>.gif` (changing the value for `delay`, if necessary) in the command line (this requires ImageMagick installed).

Comment: :I installed ImageMagick. I used the following command `convert -verbose -delay 120 -loop 0 -density 300 trial1.pdf jd.gif` but I got the long error. `"gswin32c.exe" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=50000
0000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGra
phicsAlphaBits=4 "-r300x300"  "-sOutputFile=C:/TEMP/magick-12612uP88EWl_FccC%d"
"-fC:/TEMP/magick-12612SAwashIiKLvt" "-fC:/TEMP/magick-12612CMOt26ylgf3K"
convert.exe: `%s' (%d) "gswin32c.exe" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOP` and continued

Comment: @Jdbaba that is not an error message; it's ImageMagick telling you what is happening in the conversion; to get rid of those messages, don't pass the `-verbose` option: `convert -delay 120 -loop 0 -density 300 <file>.pdf <file>.gif`

Comment: I don't know what's going on. I went and checked `convert -list configure` and in the delegates it shows `bzlib freetype jpeg jp2 lcms png tiff x11 xml wmf zlib` but it doesn't show `pdf`. Is something wrong on my version ?

Comment: Figured it out. I had to install ghostscript for pdf to work. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jdbaba ah, OK. Glad it worked.